# English phrase rebuses

Tags: rebus, english

Find three popular phrases:

> 1. raport
> 2. ga me
> 3. hbianrdd = btwusoh

Answer (score 10):

raport

> This is an anagram for both **parrot** and **raptor**, so I have three guesses:
>
>  - Flipping the bird
>  - Kill two birds with one stone
>  - Birds of a feather flock together

ga me

> total guess, but I'm going with *waiting game*

hbianrdd = btwusoh

> **hbianrdd** is an anagram of **bird hand**
>  **btwusoh** is an anagram of **two bush**
>  i.e,
>  **h***bi***an***rd***d** = **b***tw***us***o***h**
>
>  So it's *A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush*

Comment: number 3 is correct,

Comment: number 1 doesn't make me happy

Comment: @JonMarkPerry number 1 wouldn't have anything to do with pictures then, would it?

Comment: Speculating in rot13 for 1. Onq enccbeg

Comment: How about "space game" for the second one?

Comment: I'm a little confused, these are fun, but why would a phrase rebus be in anagram form or encrypted? An ordinary rebus is not.

Comment: @John If you look closely, you might notice that the letters in the two halves are still in the original order, even if they are interspersed. Note also that the first words of each half are wholly inside the second words. It's just a slightly more obfuscated version of (as an example) "midmeetdle"

Answer (score 5):

**Partial answer**

2. ga me

> It’s a game of two halves

Or possibly (As @Hugh pointed out)

> Get in the game

Comment: For that one I was thinking halftime or a break(pause) in the game.

Comment: @Z.Dailey Halftime is not possible for obvious reasons. 'A break in the game' has been already tried by Gamow

Comment: Or possibly "get in the game"

Comment: ga/me - so game of 2 halves - well done!

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Does number 1 has something to do with 'report'?

Comment: @manshu; no, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer for 1. 
 
Edit second try

> Sick as a parrot   
>  First try: Parrot-fashion : http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/parrot-fashion

Comment: close, almost, not quite..

Comment: correct eventually :)

Comment: I don't know where OP lives, but I've never heard that idiom even once in my life and wouldn't think it's considered "popular." o_o